# EF migrations claims there were changes in the context while there were none

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework Migrations & Code First and recently encountered a very weird problem.
The problem was reproduced with versions 4.3.1 and 4.4.

EF thinks that the context was changed while actually it didn't.
It happens when I change the path of the solution. for example:
If my solution is located in C:\integration\something.sln the migration may work but if now I will change the path to C:\development\something.sln and re-build the solution the migration will throw an exception saying there are pending changes in the database. (Of course without any changes in the source code.

I used IL Disassembler to create a dump of the output assemblies and with BeyondCompare I saw that there are differences. I assume the data is the same but its written in different order...

How EF determines if there were changes in the context? Is it possible that the assembly check-sum comes out different and will cause EF to think that there were changes?

Any ideas are most welcome...

Comment: What do you mean by changing the path? What differences are between solutions? Model changes are detected from hashes. If anything related to mapping changes (even order) the hash will be different.

Comment: By changing the path I mean renaming the folder - as simple as that.
It's the same solution without any changes in the code, just renamed the folder that contains it.
And what I saw is that building the same solution while it is contained in two different folders - will result in assemblies that are not the same.

So there are two issues here:
1. Visual Studio is not consistent with its output assemblies.
2. EF will get confused if the same code will result in assemblies that differ from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is not a migration issue - its probably a bug in the Entity Framework's algorithm to check if there are changes in the database.

I had a class hierarchy that contained an abstract class with no properties, making that class not abstract solved the problem.

After gaining some precious debugging experience, I found several ways to solve this issue and each one raised more eyebrows than the one before which makes me very convinced that I fell on a very rare corner case. As I mentioned, I decided to solve by making a class not abstract.

I tried to reproduce the bug in a clean solution so I can send it to Microsoft but until now it didn't really work.

So... to sum things up, if you find yourself with such a problem (very frustrating one), a good tip is to look for abstract classes!